# How to pass params to Task Queue?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, task-queue, flask-restful

I am about to implement a Push Task queue in Flask/Google App Engine.
Essentially I would like to POST to the API and execute the underlying work in the task queue.

The initial entry point is a REST API (flask_restful)

```
class FTRecordsAPI(Resource):
    def post(self):
        arguments = self.reqparser.parse_args()
        json_records = arguments.get('records')
        user = User.query(...).get()
        if user:
            taskqueue.add(url='/worker/', params={'user': user})
            return '', 201
        else:
            return '', 401
```

The worker is defined as a view in the url.py:

```
app.add_url_rule('/worker', 'worker',
                 view_func=csrf_protect.exempt(TaskView.as_view('taskView')))
```

And the TaskView is:

```
from flask.globals import request

class TaskView(MethodView):
    def post(self):
        user = request.json['user']
        return "OK"
```

Strangely when I debug in the `TaskView` nowhere in the request object is any trace of the user object I sent to the `/worker`.  However I find in there the `records` object which was from the previous call ?!

What am I missing please?

Comment: are you sure it is going to the taskqueue.add line? Does the task get created? maybe your url should be /worker instead of /worker/ ?

Comment: yes, my breakpoint in `TaskView` -> `user = request.json['user']` actually breaks. It definitely gets in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

`taskqueue.add(url='/worker', params={'user': user}, method="POST")`

and

`user = request.form.get('user')`

As marcadian pointed out, taskqueue uses `POST` by default, so perhaps you need the `request.form` to access the POST vars.

Comment: by default it is using POST

Comment: I checked just in debugger and `request.form` is an empty dictionary.

Comment: I came across an interesting case. In my Eclipse/debug I get the behaviour as described above.  However if deployed properly, I actually see `user` in `request.form`. How strange.

Comment: Are you sure the same user exists in both production and development?  Try logging `user` at each step, starting in `FTRecordsAPI`.  I assume you have taskqueue working in development?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the thread resurrection, but should you want to use json directly you can do the following for instance:

```
taskstop = taskqueue.add(url='/stop_std_watcher',
                                    target='worker',
                                    payload=json.dumps({'watcherjson': client.client_watcher}),
                                    method='POST',
                                    headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
```

the important bits being to add the `headers` and `payload` kwargs

On the receiving end, you got then:

```
@app.route('/stop_std_watcher', methods=['POST'])
def stop_std_watcher():
    # curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d @stop.json http://localhost:8081/stop_std_watcher
    watcherjson = request.json['watcherjson']
```

I added the curl in comments should you want to test your post route manually, can be useful